# how to send array with file and name from view to controller using ajax request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

[image]

JSON.stringify(getAllPortfolioTableData())); i.e JSON.stringify removes file while getting in controller using formcollection

```
 var formData = new FormData();  
    formData.append("Title", txtTitle);
    formData.append("PorfolioKeywords", txtKeywords);
    formData.append("PortfolioDescription", txtDescription);
    formData.append("PortfolioTableData", JSON.stringify(getAllPortfolioTableData()));
    formData.append("UrlTableData", JSON.stringify(getAllUrlTableData()));  

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
```

Comment: you can't use JSON.stringify for base64 string data. why can't you post data without JSON.stringify?

Comment: becoz i have multiple file types and files so that i put it array

Answer (score 0):

let say you have view like:

`<form id="upload-files">
    <input class="file-input" type="file" id="fileInput1" />
    <input class="file-input" type="file" id="fileInput2" />
    <input type="button" id="fileButton" value="Upload Files" /><br />
</form>`

and ajax post like:

```
$("#fileButton").click(function () {

        var fileData = new FormData();
        var files = $(".file-input");
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            fileData.append("fileInput", files[i].files[0]);
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: false, 
            processData: false, 
            data: fileData,
            success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(status);
            }
        });
    });
```

and in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFiles()
    {
        HttpFileCollectionBase files1 = Request.Files;
        for (int i = 0; i < files1.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = files1[i];
        }
        return Json(files1.Count + " Files Uploaded!");
    }
```

same way you can append other inputs too.

hope this helps